# Is there a way to schedule a job in Toad so that it returns counts every 3 hours?

Tags: sql, oracle, automation, jobs, toad

I am looking to monitor counts for multiple tables in the coming week in Oracle Toad DB v12.9.071.

Right now I am monitoring counts manually every 2 hrs and it's turning out to be a tedious task.

My queries look something like this:

```
select count(*), col1 from table_name where condition_1, condition_2
group by col1

select count(*), col2 from table_name2 where condition_3, condition_4
group by col2
```

And storing these outputs in my own excel. Is there a way I can schedule something in Toad such that it runs these queries every 2hr's and stores these outputs preferably in an excel file in mine system?

I am new to toad and this is a production environment so I don't want to mess up anything or do anything which might have an impact to this production DB.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduler job:

```
    BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'SELECTER'
      ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020/08/24 03:26:36.296851 +01:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzr')
      ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
      ,job_action      => 'BEGIN
-- here you need to implement your code that gets saved into a file
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE;
 END;'
```

After  this you need  to find a way of saving output to a file. I suggest you follow this guide:
http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2011/09/create-csv-file-using-plsql.html